# ng-repeat run as many times as integer parameter doesn't work in some cases

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to run angular as many times as integer value passed to it.

**EDIT**: I simplified this example because originally I used function to return array based on number passed to it.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="userFilterModule">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="UserfilterController as Ctrl">
         <div class="row">
             <div class="filter_tableTbody col-xs-12">                        
                <div class="row filter_tableRow" ng-repeat="user in Ctrl.obj_users">
                    <!-- ... -->
                    <div class="col-xs-2">
                        <span class="filter_rateStars" ng-repeat="a in Ctrl.ratingArr| limitTo: user.rate">    
                            &#x2605;
                         </span>
                         <span class="filter_rateStars notActive" ng-repeat="a in Ctrl.ratingArr| limitTo: 5 - user.rate">    
                            &#x2606;
                         </span>
                    </div>                    
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>                
</body>
```

And everything works fine if `ratingArr` contains numbers e.g.

```
app.controller('UserfilterController', function ($scope) {
    this.int_male_counter = this.int_female_counter = 5;
    this.str_sort_by = {
        prop_name: 'f_name',
        order: 'asc'
    };

    //problem starts here
    this.ratingArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

    this.obj_users = new Users(this.int_male_counter, this.int_female_counter).list;
    this.fn_set_sorting = function (str) {
        if (this.str_sort_by.prop_name === str) {
            this.str_sort_by.order = this.str_sort_by.order === 'des' ? 'asc' : 'des';                
        } else {
            this.str_sort_by.order = 'asc';
            this.str_sort_by.prop_name = str;                
        }
        this.obj_users.sortByObjKeyVal(this.str_sort_by.prop_name, this.str_sort_by.order);
    };
    this.fn_setlected_filter = function (str) {
        return str === this.str_sort_by.prop_name;
    };
    this.fn_is_descending = function(){
        return this.str_sort_by.order === 'des';
    };      
});
```

But when I change it to `new Array(5)` or `['','','','','']` or `['a','a','a','a','a']`

I get error in console: `Error: [ngRepeat:dupes]` why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, you cannot use identical values in the array processed by `ng-repeat`. [**Quoting the docs**](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes):

> `error:dupes`
>
> `Duplicate Key in Repeater`
>
> Occurs if there are duplicate keys in an `ngRepeat` expression.
>   Duplicate keys are banned because AngularJS uses keys to associate DOM
>   nodes with items.
>
> By default, collections are keyed by reference which is desirable for
>   most common models but can be problematic for primitive types that are
>   interned (share references).

As advised in the same docs, just use `track by $index` suffix (so that items will be keyed by their position in the array instead of their value) to resolve the issue:

```
<span class="filter_rateStars" 
      ng-repeat="a in Ctrl.ratingArr | limitTo: user.rate track by $index">
```

Comment: Thakns, however after that change limitTo seems to stop work and in both cases limitTo: user.rate and limitTo: 5 - user.rate returning me 5 elements...

Comment: @Etsitra Sorry, for a moment forgot that `track by...` should be the last part of the expression.